# Is there a way to use facial recognition for login and approval of sudo actions?

Tags: 20.04

It's kinda tiring to type password on boot, and it'd very nice if facial recognition could be used for using sudo command. Is it possible?

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/face-unlock-ubuntu/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! There is... You can use [Howdy](https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy) which "provides Windows Hello™ style authentication for Linux."

**Installation**

Install Howdy using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:boltgolt/howdy
sudo apt install build-essential libx11-dev howdy
```

**Configuration**

You *may* need to set the device path for your camera. For example, on my system it is `/dev/video0`:

```
sed -i "s|^device_path =.*none|# &\ndevice_path = /dev/video0|g" /lib/security/howdy/config.ini
```

Also, you can change the preciseness of the face matching algorithm. On a scale from 1 (low precision) to 10 (high precision), values above 5 are not recommended; lower is better:

```
sed -i "s|^certainty = 3.5|# certainty = 3.5\ncertainty = 4.2|g" /lib/security/howdy/config.ini
```

**Recording your face model**

To record your face, execute `sudo howdy add` to add face models for the current user. To add face models for other users, use `sudo howdy add --user other_user_name`.

For example here is how you would add a face model for yourself, where `my_user_name` is your user name. You can record multiple face models for each user as long as you give each model a unique name.

```
sudo howdy add
No face model known
[sudo] password for my_user_name: 
No face model folder found, creating one
Adding face model for the user my_user_name
Enter a label for this new model [Initial model] (max 24 characters): my_user_name_01           

Please look straight into the camera
Scan complete

Added a new model to my_user_name
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. Thank you